# Conditional formatting for a single cell based on a row being empty or containing any values

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want A1 to go green if any cells in range B1:J1 contain any values.

A1 to remain blank if B1:J1 contain no values.

In the sheet all values will be text based but will vary from cell to cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional formatting with *custom formula*

```
=len(join("", B1:1))
```

The join concatenates all the values in that row, starting with B1. The formatting applies if the length of the concatenated string is not zero.

Comment: Awesome - that works perfect! :)